# Do I need to replace old virtual env with new inside django project?

Tags: django, virtualenv

I had to run an old django project in a new virtual environment to see if I could make migrations as it wouldn't work for the original virtual env. In this other virtual env I already just had a basic project so I think it's ok to reuse the name.
However, my old project still has the old virtual environment in the project directory. Should I delete it, and replace with this new one, or just continue running project in new environment without adding new virtual env to the project?

Comment: A virtual environment is used for having your projects appropriate python versions. Whether a project is new or old doesn't matter as long as the current environment lets your app run.  Not sure exactly what your asking though. What have you tried?

Comment: I meant that the original virtual environment I created for the project became buggy, so I created a new virtual env, and ran the project from there without any issues. But inside the project directory, is still the original virtual environment. I'm wondering do I need to change it in the project directory, or just leave it as it is?

Comment: I would say just use the new one and delete the old one completely.